# Ubuntu 18 partition error

Tags: ubuntu, boot, partitioning, raid, efi

I'm new on Linux, just created VROC NVMe RAID1 and installed Ubuntu 18.04.3 on it. Then noticed that `lsblk` gives an error: "GPT PMBR size mismatch (1781612543 != 1875385007) will be corrected by w(rite)". So I decided to fix it with `parted -l`. Now my Ubutu become unbootable: boot disk not visible. State before is presented on pic 1, and state after on pic 2. Please help how to turn it back.
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TFgV.png)
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxlKA.png)

Comment: What error do you get when you try boot it? Are you doing a uefi boot?

Comment: Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems: 1. Boot args. 2. Check rootdelay. 3. Missing modules. ALERT! UUID=... does not exist. UEFI.

Comment: (After backing it up) maybe try modify /etc/fstab - either replace the UUID's with /dev/blockname or update its UUID's in line with the output from lsblk or similar.